# spark-submit with external python packages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, textblob

I am using the python textblob package to calculate the sentiment in a spark job. In order to make the textblob package available on the spark cluster, I created a virtual environment, installed the textblob package in there and packed it using venv-pack. The resulting archive is then used as a parameter for the `--archives` flag of `spark-submit`. Eventually, I set the environment variables according to the python package management section of the spark documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-virtualenv):

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python # Do not set in cluster modes.
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python
spark-submit --archives pyspark_venv.tar.gz#environment app.py
```

When I execute the spark-submit command, the application tells me that it could not find the textblob package.

I am trying to make this setup work for days. I already tried using conda, pex and the --py-files option but none of it worked. Am I missing something?

Eventually, I ended up installing textblob directly on the spark-master machine which seems to work, but I'd rather stick to the documented way.